# CUDA Nsight - find out what CPU is doing between kernel/runtime api calls

Tags: visual-studio, cuda, profiling, nvidia, nsight

I'm wondering if there's any way to discover in Nsight what CPU function calls are made between two runtime API/driver or kernel calls (an image's worth a thousand words):

[image]

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the [NVIDA Tools Extension API](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/NsightVisualStudio/3.0/Documentation/UserGuide/HTML/Nsight_Visual_Studio_Edition_User_Guide.htm#NVIDIA_Tools_Extension_Library_NVTX.htm%3FTocPath%3DNVIDIA%20Nsight%20Visual%20Studio%20Edition%203.0%20User%20Guide%7CAnalysis%20Tools%7CThe%20NVIDIA%20Tools%20Extension%20Library%20%28NVTX%29%7C_____0) you can get a variety of information about CPU activity (in addition to GPU activity) in the Nsight VSE profiler display.

There are a variety of examples given in the Nsight VSE 3.0 documentation.

The [same API](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html#marking-regions-of-cpu-activity) works with the [standalone visual profiler -- nvvp](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html).

Comment: @David In the Analysis Activity Editor under Trace Settings you can enable System trace provider and the sub-option CPU Thread Trace. This will add Thread State rows into the Timeline. This row can be used to determine if the thread was running, sleeping, or blocked during the 1ms blank interval.